# Facebooks new auth dialog not working?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Not sure if Facebooks new auth dialog (beta) as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/) is working. I have enabled it in my apps advanced settings, but it still shows the *old* dialog.

Url is constructed like this:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=XXX&display=popup&next=XXX8&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&fbconnect=1&perms=create_event%2Cpublish_actions&sdk=joey

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently publish_actions permission only works for game apps even if you enabled the new Auth dialog.

For your users to see the new OAuth dialog, you need to add them to your app's testers. Otherwise, they will still get the old dialog.